# Trouble posting CREATERAWTRANSACTION to Bitcoin Core via JSON-RPC

Tags: c#, json, json.net, bitcoin, json-rpc

I'm trying to post to a local bitcoin full node via `json-rpc` but I'm getting an error from the server.

Following the documentation here:
https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.17.0/rpc/rawtransactions/createrawtransaction/

I can see the following example structure for a `createrawtransaction` request:

```
{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "createrawtransaction", "params": ["[{\"txid\":\"myid\",\"vout\":0}]", "[{\"address\":0.01}]"] }
```

My code creates the following structure, which seems to match the structure of the example from bitcoincore.org:

```
{"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"1","method":"createrawtransaction","params":["[{\"txid\":\"1a43a1f27c5837d5319a45217aa948a4d39c1d89faf497ce59de5bd570a64a26\",\"vout\":1}]","[{\"2NAZpRsvj9BstxxCDkKoe1FVjmPPxdmvqKj\":0.01}]"]}
```

But it gives an error:

```
System.Net.WebException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
  Source=RawTransactions
  StackTrace:
   at RawTransactions.Form1.RequestServer(String methodName, List`1 parameters) in C:\Users\userthree\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\RawTransactions\RawTransactions\Form1.cs:line 132
   at RawTransactions.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\userthree\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\RawTransactions\RawTransactions\Form1.cs:line 77
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at RawTransactions.Program.Main() in C:\Users\userthree\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\RawTransactions\RawTransactions\Program.cs:line 19
```

Below is the method I am using to make the RPC request, which I got from the API reference here:

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)#.NET_.28C.23.29

```
public static string RequestServer(string methodName, List<string> parameters)
{
    string ServerIp = "http://localhost:18332";
    string UserName = "USERNAME";
    string Password = "PASSWORD";

    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ServerIp);
    webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);

    webRequest.ContentType = "application/json-rpc";
    webRequest.Method = "POST";

    string respVal = string.Empty;

    JObject joe = new JObject();
    joe.Add(new JProperty("jsonrpc", "1.0"));
    joe.Add(new JProperty("id", "1"));
    joe.Add(new JProperty("method", methodName));

    JArray props = new JArray();
    foreach (var parameter in parameters)
    {
        props.Add(parameter);
    }

    joe.Add(new JProperty("params", props));

    // serialize json for the request
    string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(joe);
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
    webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

    Stream dataStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();

    StreamReader streamReader = null;
    try
    {
        WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();

        streamReader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), true);

        respVal = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(respVal).ToString();
        return data;
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        throw (exp);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (streamReader != null)
        {
            streamReader.Close();
        }
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

Here is my attempt to use the above method:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();

    sb1.Append("[{\"");
    sb1.Append("txid");
    sb1.Append("\":\"");
    sb1.Append(Convert.ToString(data["result"][Convert.ToInt32(txtFromJSON.Text)]["txid"]));
    sb1.Append("\",\"");
    sb1.Append("vout");
    sb1.Append("\":");
    sb1.Append(Convert.ToString(data["result"][Convert.ToInt32(txtFromJSON.Text)]["vout"]));
    sb1.Append("}]");

    StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();

    sb2.Append("[{\"");
    sb2.Append(Convert.ToString(data["result"][Convert.ToInt32(txtToJSON.Text)]["address"]));
    sb2.Append("\":");
    sb2.Append(txtAmountToSpend.Text);
    sb2.Append("}]");

    // {"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"1","method":"createrawtransaction","params":["[{\"txid\":\"1a43a1f27c5837d5319a45217aa948a4d39c1d89faf497ce59de5bd570a64a26\",\"vout\":1}]","[{\"2NAZpRsvj9BstxxCDkKoe1FVjmPPxdmvqKj\":0.01}]"]}
    data = JObject.Parse(RequestServer("createrawtransaction", new List<string>() { Convert.ToString(sb1), Convert.ToString(sb2) }));

    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(data));
}
```

Other commands such these as do work:

```
// {"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"1","method":"sendtoaddress","params":["2N8hwP1WmJrFF5QWABn38y63uYLhnJYJYTF","0.1"]}
data = JObject.Parse(RequestServer("sendtoaddress", new List<string>() { "2N8hwP1WmJrFF5QWABn38y63uYLhnJYJYTF", Convert.ToString(0.1) } ));
```

This also works:

```
// {"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"1","method":"listunspent","params":[]}
data = JObject.Parse(RequestServer("listunspent", new List<String>() { }));
```

**My Question:**

What have I done wrong with `createrawtransaction`?

---

**Update 1:**

As suggested in the comments, I have changed the `StringBuilder`, and am now using objects and then serializing the objects using Newtonsoft.Json.

Here is my second attempt to use the API reference code from https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)#.NET_.28C.23.29:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    JContainer jArray = new JArray();

    JObject jFromTx = new JObject
    {
        { "txid", data["result"][Convert.ToInt32(txtFromJSON.Text)]["txid"] },
        { "vout", data["result"][Convert.ToInt32(txtFromJSON.Text)]["vout"] }
    };

    jArray.Add(jFromTx);

    JObject jToTx = new JObject
    {
        { Convert.ToString(data["result"][Convert.ToInt32(txtToJSON.Text)]["address"]), Convert.ToDouble(txtAmountToSpend.Text) }
    };

    JContainer jArray2 = new JArray
    {
        jToTx
    };

    string strFrom = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jArray);
    string strTo = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jArray2);

    data = JObject.Parse(RequestServer("createrawtransaction", new List<string>() { strFrom, strTo }));
}
```

Here is the new serialized JSON:

```
{"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"1","method":"createrawtransaction","params":["[{\"txid\":\"1a43a1f27c5837d5319a45217aa948a4d39c1d89faf497ce59de5bd570a64a26\",\"vout\":1}]","[{\"2NAZpRsvj9BstxxCDkKoe1FVjmPPxdmvqKj\":0.01}]"]}
```

Compared to the old StringBuilder JSON from my first attempt:

```
{"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"1","method":"createrawtransaction","params":["[{\"txid\":\"1a43a1f27c5837d5319a45217aa948a4d39c1d89faf497ce59de5bd570a64a26\",\"vout\":1}]","[{\"2NAZpRsvj9BstxxCDkKoe1FVjmPPxdmvqKj\":0.01}]"]}
```

I am still getting the same error message as before (see above).

Comment: Instead of trying to string together JSON via a stringbuilder, what you should do instead is create some sensible DTO objects to populate with data, and then use Newtonsoft JSON to serialize those object to valid JSON.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - As suggested, I have tried using objects, then using Newtonsoft.Json to serialize it to valid json.  But I'm still getting the same error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* the problem is your `params` array is getting double-serialized, so the server doesn't know how to interpret the request.  I do realize that your JSON looks the same as the example, so I could very well be wrong here; I'm definitely not an expert on using Bitcoin Core's API.  However, I did look at a the source code for a [third-party library](https://github.com/cryptean/bitcoinlib) which is supposed to be compatible with Bitcoin Core, and it does not appear to double-serialize the parameters for the `createrawtransation` request.  This leads me to believe that the double-serialized parameters are the problem.

To fix, try the following:

1. Change the method signature for your existing `RequestServer` method from this:

   ```
   public static string RequestServer(string methodName, List<string> parameters)
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   public static string RequestServer(string methodName, List<JToken> parameters)
   ```
2. Create a new overload of the `RequestServer` method using the old signature which calls the existing one you just changed.  This will allow your other methods which already work (e.g. `sendtoaddress` and `listunspent`) to keep working with no changes.

   ```
   public static string RequestServer(string methodName, List<string> parameters)
   {
       return RequestServer(methodName, parameters.Select(p => new JValue(p)).ToList<JToken>());
   }
   ```
3. Lastly, change the code in your `button1_Click` method so that it does not serialize `jArray` and `jArray2`, but instead passes them in a `List<JToken>` to `RequestServer`.  In other words, change this code:

   ```
   string strFrom = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jArray);
   string strTo = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jArray2);

   data = JObject.Parse(RequestServer("createrawtransaction", new List<string>() { strFrom, strTo }));
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   data = JObject.Parse(RequestServer("createrawtransaction", new List<JToken>() { jArray, jArray2 }));
   ```

With these changes, the RPC JSON for `createrawtransaction` should end up looking like this:

```
{"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"1","method":"createrawtransaction","params":[[{"txid":"1a43a1f27c5837d5319a45217aa948a4d39c1d89faf497ce59de5bd570a64a26","vout":1}],[{"2NAZpRsvj9BstxxCDkKoe1FVjmPPxdmvqKj":0.01}]]}
```

Notice that the extra quotes and backslashes in the `params` array are gone.  Compare to what you had before:

```
{"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"1","method":"createrawtransaction","params":["[{\"txid\":\"1a43a1f27c5837d5319a45217aa948a4d39c1d89faf497ce59de5bd570a64a26\",\"vout\":1}]","[{\"2NAZpRsvj9BstxxCDkKoe1FVjmPPxdmvqKj\":0.01}]"]}
```

Comment: This works Brian.  Thanks for the help.  Not sure if I was using the wrong example json structure, or if the documentation is wrong, as I was unable to use `curl` to run the example given.  But your changes seem to be working perfectly.  Thanks!