# Unable to post GETBLOCKHASH to Bitcoin Core via JSON-RPC

Tags: c#, json, json.net, bitcoin, json-rpc

The following code works fine for the most part:

```
public static string RequestServer(string methodName, List<string> parameters)
{
    // Use the values you specified in the bitcoin server command line
    string ServerIp = "http://localhost.:8332";
    string UserName = "username";
    string Password = "password";

    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ServerIp);
    webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);

    webRequest.ContentType = "application/json-rpc";
    webRequest.Method = "POST";

    string responseValue = string.Empty;

    // Configure request type
    JObject joe = new JObject();
    joe.Add(new JProperty("jsonrpc", "1.0"));
    joe.Add(new JProperty("id", "1"));
    joe.Add(new JProperty("method", methodName));

    JArray props = new JArray();
    foreach (var parameter in parameters)
    {
        props.Add(parameter);
    }

    joe.Add(new JProperty("params", props));

    // serialize JSON for request
    string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(joe);
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
    webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    Stream dataStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();

    // deserialze the response
    StreamReader sReader = null;
    WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
    sReader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), true);
    responseValue = sReader.ReadToEnd();

    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseValue).ToString();
    
    return data;
}
```

I can then use a `methodName` such as `getnewaddress` to get data back from the server:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(RequestServer("getnewaddress", new List<string>(){"","legacy"}));
}
```

That will return something like this:

```
{
  "result": "1EWJkGrirdhXpduoNdccxaCx7syqWHuDcK",
  "error": null,
  "id": "1"
}
```

The above methodName works fine when using the terminal too:

```
bitcoin@desktop:~/Downloads/bitcoin-0.20.0-x86_64-linux-gnu/bitcoin-0/bin$ ./bitcoin-cli getnewaddress "" "legacy"
1EWJkGrirdhXpduoNdccxaCx7syqWHuDcK
bitcoin@desktop:~/Downloads/bitcoin-0.20.0-x86_64-linux-gnu/bitcoin-0.20.0/bin$
```

I can use a few methodNames the same way and they work fine.  However, when I use `getblockhash`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(RequestServer("getblockhash", new List<string>(){"0"}));
}
```

It gives me the following error:

```
bitcoin@desktop:~/Code/blockchain-app$ dotnet run
Unhandled exception. System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at blockchain-app.Program.RequestServer(String methodName, List`1 parameters) in /home/bitcoin/Code/blockchain-app/Program.cs:line 72
   at blockchain-app.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/bitcoin/Code/blockchain-app/Program.cs:line 29
bitcoin@desktop:~/Code/blockchain-app$
```

When debugging, the error happens on this line:

```
WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
```

If I try to check the output manually using that methodName in the terminal such as the following, it works fine:

```
bitcoin@desktop:~/Downloads/bitcoin-0.20.0-x86_64-linux-gnu/bitcoin-0.20.0/bin$ ./bitcoin-cli getblockhash 0
000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f
bitcoin@desktop:~/Downloads/bitcoin-0.20.0-x86_64-linux-gnu/bitcoin-0.20.0/bin$
```

The request example structures look the same to me other than the methodName and the parameters sent:

https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.20.0/rpc/wallet/getnewaddress/
https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.20.0/rpc/blockchain/getblockhash/

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Did you check the response body to see if there was any error details?

Comment: Unsure how to check the response body.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828843/webexception-how-to-get-whole-response-with-a-body the body probably has some sort of error reason.

Comment: @Charleh, that helped me fine the issue.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: Cool, post your solution as an answer if you want, might help someone in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* the problem is that you are passing the wrong parameter type for the height index when calling `getblockhash`.  The documentation you linked to says that it should be a numeric (integer) parameter, but you are passing a string.  In contrast, the `getnewaddress` method uses string parameters, so your existing code works for that.

If you capture the JSON that is being generated by your `RequestServer` method, it looks like this:

```
{"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"1","method":"getblockhash","params":["0"]}
```

But the sample in the documentation for `getblockhash` looks like this:

```
{"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"curltest","method":"getblockhash","params":[1000]}
```

Notice that the value in the `params` array is not quoted in the sample, whereas it is quoted in yours.

To fix, try the following:

1. Change the method signature for your existing `RequestServer` method from this:

   ```
   public static string RequestServer(string methodName, List<string> parameters)
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   public static string RequestServer(string methodName, List<JToken> parameters)
   ```
2. Create a new overload of the `RequestServer` method using the old signature which calls the existing one you just changed.  This will allow your other method call(s) which already work (e.g. `getnewaddress`) to keep working with no changes.

   ```
   public static string RequestServer(string methodName, List<string> parameters)
   {
       return RequestServer(methodName, parameters.Select(p => new JValue(p)).ToList<JToken>());
   }
   ```
3. Change the code which calls `getblockhash` from this:

   ```
   Console.WriteLine(RequestServer("getblockhash", new List<string>() { "0" }));
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   Console.WriteLine(RequestServer("getblockhash", new List<JToken>() { new JValue(0) }));
   ```

Note that I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53603131/10263) for you back in 2018 in which I recommended the same steps 1 and 2 shown above, so you may have already done that part.  If so, all you need to do is step 3.